# Cannot acces instance using compute ssh : "ERROR: [....putty.exe] exited with return code [1]

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

Here's my problem :
I would like to connect to a gcp instance. When I run the Google Cloud SDK shell as an administrator with the command :
gcloud compute ssh my_instance --zone=europe-west1-b -- -L=8081:locahost:8081
..I get this error : ERROR (gcloud.compute.ssh) [..../putty.exe] exited with return code [1]

My instance is running with the metadata enable-oslogin as TRUE, as the project.

Do you have an idea of what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `--` in the command, you are passing SSH flags after the dashes  and not gcloud command flags. To explain, [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#DESCRIPTION) is a thin wrapper around the ssh(1) command that takes care of authentication and the translation of the instance name into an IP address.

In this case, `--` is equivalent to `--ssh-flag` as per this [SDK reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--ssh-flag). It seems that putty is outputting an error that is not passed into the command line (SDK shell). The actual error should be visible in the dialog window before putty exits.

I have tried the command myself on Windows and the exact error was `unknown option "L=8081:localhost:8081"`. The SSH flag is not accepted as you have an `=` sign there (typo).

According to [linuxcommand.org manual](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ssh1.html), the flag should be in this format:

```
-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
```

Hence, you should run the command like this:

```
gcloud compute ssh my_instance --zone=europe-west1-b -- -L 8081:locahost:8081
```

Note also that you may have to create a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) to allow Ingress to the instance on port 8081.